# Use sidekiq delay in service objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am currently replacing delayed job worker with sidekiq worker in my rails application.I need to use delay in service objects.I have created an object for that service and called service method in delay but it throws undefined method delay for Service.

***sidekiq.rb***

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
end

Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { retry: 10}

Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { 'backtrace' => true }
```

**new_registration_service.rb:**

```
class NewRegistrationService
  def initialize(params)
    @user = params[:user]
    @organization = params[:organization]
  end
  def mark
    @user.generate_marks
  end
end
```

In rails console,when I try to call **NewRegistrationService.new({user: resource, organization: @org}).delay.mark** , it shows undefined method delay for that object

Comment: Hey Mohan, Weclome to Stack Overflow, Can you post some code about what you've tried till and now and where are you stuck? I would request you to have a look at the Question Asking guidelines.

Comment: What have **you** tried so far. We'll need a bit more context and code to debug.

Comment: I have added code